# How to scrape content inside multiple links, using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Context:  I'm trying to scrape a news website for a data science project. I want to scrape all the articles present inside a certain category of that news website.

My Approach: To attempt this, I tried making a crawler which follows links and scrapes the inside contents of those links.

Problem: The problem I faced was that I could not make my crawler iterate over the links and scrape them, instead it just returned with the content of only the first one.

My code: Below in the code `parse` method tries to get all the individual article links present on that page, and redirects them to `parse_contents` method which tries to scrape the inside contents of those articles.

Kindly suggest me a method to achieve the result, or point out mistakes in my approach.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ETtestItem

class ETtestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'etTest'
    start_urls = [
        'https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/auto/auto-news/articlelist/64829342.cms'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

# This worked to extract single top article

        article = s.response.css('div.eachStory a::attr(href)').get()
        if article is not None:
            for a in article:
                yield response.follow(article, callback=self.parse_contents)


    def parse_contents (self, response):
        full_article = response.css('div.relative')
        items = ETtestItem()

        for t in full_article:
            title = t.css('.title::text').extract()
            summary = t.css('.title2::text').extract()
            text = t.css('.Normal::text').extract()
            tags = t.css('.rdMrBulDiv a::text').extract()

            items['title'] = title
            items['summary'] = summary
            items['text'] = text
            items['tags'] = tags

            yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code is working for me.

Just replace for i in range(1, max page to scape)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time

binary = r'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
gecko = r'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\geckodriver.exe'

options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=False)
options.binary = binary

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True #optional



driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path= gecko)
driver.maximize_window() 
driver.implicitly_wait(15) 

for i in range(1,2):
    driver.get('https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/ile_de_france/p-'+str(i)+'/')
    time.sleep(15)
    print(driver.page_source)
```